# calling myTimer.cancel() won't stop the timer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

```
      private class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer{
       public MyTimer(long timeLeft,long timeInterval){
        super(timeLeft,timeInterval);
      }
      public void onTick(long timeToGo){
        //code to execute on every tick
      }
      public void onFinish(){
      //code to execute onFinish
      }};
```

I am trying to make an app using a timer above but  calling myTimer.cancel() won't stop the timer. Pls help. The timer continue counting

Comment: How and where are you calling it?

Comment: Well here is the answer to my question. 1.add MyTimer myTimer; in yo Global variable. 2. in onCreate() add this>> myTimer=new MyTimer(timeLeft,interval) from there you can call your timer from other methods like this myTimer.cancel(). It worked for me, after 2 days of hesitations.